# Strang, Introd. to Linear Algebra, Section 3.3, Problem 27: Finding a right inverse given a rank $r$ matrix of dimensions $m$ by $n$ defined in blocks

Tags: linear-algebra, solution-verification, proof-explanation

The following problem appears in section 3.3 of Gilbert Strang's *Introduction to Linear Algebra*

> 27 Suppose $R$ is $m$ by $n$ of rank $r$, with pivot columns first
>
> $$R=\begin{bmatrix}I&F\\ 0&0 \end{bmatrix}\tag{1}$$
>
> (a) What are the shapes of those four blocks?
>
> (b) Find a right-inverse $B$ with $RB=I$ if $r=m$.

My question concerns item (b).

Just as a side note, though I am asking about item (b), there are three additional items in this question ((c)-(e)).

First let's just solve item (a). The matrix in (1) is in row reduced form and the pivots must all be in the matrix $I$, which must be $r$ by $r$. From this information we know the dimensions of the other matrices: $F$ is $r$ by $n-r$, the left-hand $0$ matrix is $m-r$ by $r$ and the right-hand $0$ matrix is $m-r$ by $n-r$.

The solution manual has a very terse solution (for all the items in the problem). Besides the dimensions that we derived above it says simply

> $$\text{rref}(R^T)=\begin{bmatrix}I&0\\ 0&0\end{bmatrix}$$
>
> $$\text{rref}(R^TR)=\text{ same as } R$$

I assume rref means reduced row echelon form.

What exactly is happening in the solution presented by the solution manual above?

**Here is what I had came up with.**

Since $r=m$,

- we must have $n\geq m$ (otherwise, we wouldn't be able to have $r=m$ pivots, since there would be $n<m=r$ columns)
- thus, we might have free variables (represented by the columns to the right of $I$)
- the two zero blocks aren't present (otherwise we'd have $r<m$).
- therefore, $R=[I\ F]$ with $I$ being $r$ by $r$ and $F$ being $r$ by $n-r$.
- $R$ is in row reduced echelon form.

Comment: How about 

$$\left[ \begin{matrix} I & F \\ \end{matrix} \right]

\left[ \begin{matrix} I  \\ 
0 \\
 \end{matrix} \right]?$$